# If you have a firebase snapshot with a filter applied to the current user’s child, how can one do that for all users in the database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If you have a firebase snapshot that you are filtering for the current user, how do you do that for all users in the database?

```
 Path: (people.child(uid).child(peopleWhoLike2)
```

It works for the current user, but I want it for all users. Probably something like for peopleArray in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] { needs to be used. Below is code for current

```
        let thisUserRef1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid)
                 let myPeopleRef1 = thisUserRef1.child("peopleWhoLike2")
        myPeopleRef1.observeSingleEvent(of:DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        print("klk")
         
         let peopleArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            let filteredResults = peopleArray.filter { person in
                let personUid = person.value as! Int
                let coordSnap12 = personUid
                
            
            print("kjk", coordSnap12 )
                       let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(coordSnap12)/1000.0)
                       //let secondsInDay = 86400
                  
                return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date)

                }
            
            
            print(filteredResults, "ppp")
            let countb = filteredResults.compactMap({$0}).count
            print(countb, "ccc")
```

JSON DB Structure

```
"people" : {
"1ZWT7FAE2qThNQfBj7tbMO7BnMo1" : {
  "Coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 50.054738,
    "longitude" : 8.226809826085624
  "peopleWhoLike2" : {
    "1vLVFwrXrHUoakmDrnQKwbv08Yj1" : 1581548952597,
    "F9NX0UCG4fVHCKFk2VZ1NZKsLro2" : 1586210112155,
    "IrrBgFY9C1ekMmHUkQRzc5LhbDu1" : 1581547417432,
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. It works for the current user - but you want it for all users. What is 'it'? What's the expected result? Can you add a snippet of your Firebase structure to your question so we can understand what your data looks like (add it as text please, no screenshot).

Comment: @Jay Sure thing. I'll add JSON to the question. I need print(countb, "ccc") for all users, not just the logged in user. ccc represents a count of timestamps in today, from that child peoplewholike2. Basically need that for all users. Does that make sense? What I want to do with this is display all users in rank, according to who has higher ccc count. But before I can do that, I need to do this count for all users, not just the logged in one.

Comment: *ccc represents a count of timestamps in today* but there are no timestamps in your structure. We don't know what `countb` is either. How do you identify one user from another? Is the 1ZWT7... a uid?

Comment: @Jay My bad, I cut it off too early. The timestamps are there now

Comment: countb is an array of timestamps in today for the logged in user. Yes, 1Z is uid

Comment: Is the path really */coordinates/peopleWhiLikeMe2/peopleWhoLikeMe2*? As that's kind of deep and there's usually no need for repetitive key names inside each other.

Comment: @Jay No just one. Sorry. I was distracted yesterday evening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have a direct way to get the count of number of children in a node without reading in that nodes data. So there are two methods.

1. Observe the node, iterating over the children with .childAdded to get a count. Or, along those same lines load in all of the children with .value - to which you can get a count of the snapshots children. The downside there is it could be a LOT of data so with larger datasets, or unknown amount of children this is discouraged. It's also very read heavy obviously as if you have 1000 users, it's a lot of data to parse through.
2. Keep a separate node of the child count (this is the winner!)

The additional node would look like this

```
like_me_counts
   "1ZWT7FAE2qThNQfBj7tbMO7BnMo1": 3
   "another user id": 20
   "yet another user id": 12
```

So as a user has another person like them, add the 'liker' to the "peopleWhoLike2" node as shown in your question, and then increment that users matching node within the like_me_counts node.

In this case if another person like user 1ZWT7... read that in from the like_me_counts node to get the value of 3, add one and then write out 4. If a user unlikes them, read it in, subtract 1 and write out the new value.

You can wrap all of that into a transaction so it either all succeeds or all fails.

EDIT

I would even go so far to say that it may be best to break out the people who like you into it's own node

```
like_me
   uid_0
      user_10: true
      user_11: true
   uid_1
      user_39: true
   uid_2
      user_46: true
```

What that structure, each user would add a child added observer to their like_me node, and when someone likes them... say user_52 likes user_2

```
   uid_2
      user_46: true
      user_52: true
```

then uid_2 will receive that notification and can handle it. Obviously, I am just using true as a placeholder but there could be other info such as a time stamp or even child nodes that can be used for filtering (for todays likes only for example)

```
  uid_2
     user_46: 20200624
     user_52: 20200629
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only problem with that is the count has to be continuously updated to include only the likes in the last day. That is why I used the filter in the array to return Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date). I though it would be easier to count the timestamps in firebase (representing likes) on the client device, and have the count filtered for the timestamps in today. I managed to successfully do that for the logged in user. countb for example return 5. If I could do that for all users (ie make the snapshot for all users), I thought it would be a better approach

Comment: @lakertanner The issue there is two fold - it's reading in a LOT of unnecessary data to start with and then as the data size grows, it will take longer and longer to update. If you just add an observer to the users nodes along with a filter for todays's entries only, as new likes happen *today* you can easily update the counter in the like_me_counts list. Optionally, break the peopleWhoLike2 node out into a separate node and add an observer to that parent node. Then when anyone is liked, that will be processed to the event handler and you can then update the like_me_counts node.

Comment: Hmm. How would you do either of the 2 options you mentioned in pseudocode? I thought to maybe make peopleWhoLike3 a double. As in 7:1593377892. Now if the timestamp is in today, 7 becomes 8. If it isn't, 7 become 1. Timestamp is updated both time. Do you think that would work?

Comment: @lakertanner Don't overcomplicate it. If you really want to query for nodes that match today's date, and you want to have it ongoing (instead of .observeSingleEvent) then you need to watch the clock on the device as well to remove the old query. issue a new query and update the UI when the day changes.

Comment: @lakertanner Check out my edit at the end of the question.

Comment: So I have a structure similar to that in the edit, but that still leaves the question, how do you filter it to count only the ones with timestamps from today, for all of them.

Comment: I look at everything again. Your answer makes sense, should work, and might even be beneficial when it comes to security rules. I did figure out another way to do it. In the original question I mentioned that countb is the filter count for like of current user in today. Instead of using uid, I used "the uid of the user that gets liked by current logged in user", and set the count as a child. Now I have to figure out how to rank according to the size that that child count, but for this question, the problem is solved. You're answer was good still so I'll mark it as correct.